# user input sets array length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a text box that a user puts in a number. This number will set the array length and after that the user will be prompted for numbers. The amount of times the user is prompted is based on this number. The issue I am having is I cannot get the value in the text box to set the length. here is the code that I am using

```
<script>
        var arraySize = document.getElementById("txtSize");


        function startProcess() {

           alert("the value is " + arraySize.value);



        }

     </script>
```

I just have the alert box for testing to see if it is working, but I get an error Line: 19
Error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

the rest of the HTML code is 
<

```
p>
        Enter Size of the Array:
        <input type="text" id="txtSize" value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" value=" START " onclick="startProcess()">
    </p>
    <p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Array Sum</td>
                <td>Array Product</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtSum" value="")></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtProd" value="")></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </p>
```

Comment: Are you putting the script tag before the html markup ?

Comment: Yes, I have it in the head

Comment: Because the script is in the head of the document, the element you are trying to select is not there yet. Place this inside a `window.onload` or at the end of the document, or get the element from within the function

Comment: You have to get the element in the function

Comment: Thank you Brennan and tymeJV, putting it into the function was what I needed to do. I am getting tired and bleary eyed I guess. Again thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is bad, you forgot to get the value:
`enter code here`var arraySize = document.getElementById("txtSize");

It should be like this:
 var arraySize = document.getElementById("txtSize").value;